# Integrate Vimeo API for uploading videos

Tags: javascript, php, vimeo-api

I am new in vimeo and i am just integratig the vimeo api for uploading the video.
While reserching I find git repository which is

https://github.com/websemantics/vimeo-upload

but when i am working on this i got error:

> "error": "The app is not allowed to perform that action."

Here is the api url:
https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos

[image]

Comment: It seems you will have to wait for the Vimeo Team to review your request

Comment: how much time will take the vimeo team ?

Comment: Since I am not a part of this Team, that's all, I can tell you. You might want to message the Vimeo Support if you feel like the waiting period is too long

Comment: @Karan - I'd say the answer to your question is in your image `over the next couple of days`, reading errors helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Go on vimeo-upload.js

```
me.prototype.upload = function() {
    ....
    ....
    //add
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.2')
    ....
}
```